# ¿Cómo rescato los datos enviados por formulario en Meteor.JS?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, meteor

Hola buenos dias a todos.

Tengo una pequeña consulta, que con mi poca experiencia en Meteor no puedo resolver, pero espero que ustedes puedan aydarme.

Simplemente deseo que a travès de un formulario se envíe una cadena y que esa cadena pueda rescatarla desde otra plantilla.

Este es el buscador y su codificación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<template name="buscador">
  <center>
    <div class="container centrar">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-lg-12" id="sidebar"> <!--Sidebar (Vertical)-->
          <div class="input-group buscador">
            <h2 class="fuente_buscador">Introduzca ID del investigador a buscar</h2>
            <form class="new-id" action="../startup/server.js">
                <input name="id_investigador" id="id_investigador" type="text" value="" placeholder="ID Investigador" class="form-control"/>
                <!-- <span class="input-group-btn">
                  <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button">Ir!</button>
                </span> -->
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </center>
</template>


Template.buscador.events({
  'submit form': function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    id_investigador = $(e.target).find('[name="id_investigador"]').val();
    Router.go('results', {id_investigador: id_investigador});
  }
});
```

Con esto espero que desde otra plantilla pueda imprimir o llamar al valor ingresado. Algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A continuación va la plantilla de destino:

```
<template name="perfil">
  <div class="col-md-9"> <!--Perfil investigador-->
    <center><img src="http://dsi-vd.github.io/patternlab-vd/images/fpo_avatar.png" class="img-circle imagen_perfil" alt="Cinque Terre"></center>

    <div class="thumbnail">
      <div class="caption-full">
        <h4><a href="#">Carlos Hidalgo</a></h4>
        <p>ID Investigador: {{ id_usuario }}</p>
        <p>Centro de Investigaciones Energéticas Medioambientales y Tecnológicas</p><hr>
        <p>
          Carlos Hidalgo started publishing in the year 1982, and to this date has produced 274 papers. As of today,
           Carlos Hidalgo 's h-index is 42. Carlos Hidalgo 's main fields are Physics and Astronomy, Energy, Materials
           Science
         </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Siento ocuparles tiempo. Pero necesito solucionar esto lo antes posible. De antemano muchas gracias.
Saludos

Answer (score 0):

Simplemente puedes usar *jQuery*:

```
var id_investigador = $('#id_investigador').val();
```